# Why my test files from a test folder can't import the source files from a source folder?

Tags: python, module, python-module, project-structure

I have a problem where this is my project structure:

```
.
├── Resources/
├── src/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── utils/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── util.py
│   │   └── otherUtil.py
│   └── calculations/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── financials.py
└── tests/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

My problem is that I can't reach the classes from the src/ folder from the tests, although the code in src/ can reach the Resources folder, through the first shown method.

I have tried:

1. To append the home library path this way:

   [image]

   Here I used the `from src import util` after these lines, I even tried `from .src import util`.
2. Then this way:

   [image]

   Here I used the `from src import util` after these lines, I even tried `from .src import util`.
3. Than without the `sys.path.append()` with no use.

I have tried every combination I know, but for no use, and I don't want to install them as individual packages. Does someone have an idea, witch will solve my problem?

**Clarification edit:**

I don't want to put the tests in the source folder, i want to keep them separate.

Comment: move tests to src :D

Comment: @sahasrara62 but I don't really want to, and this is why I didn't do it. Isn't there another way to make it work?

Comment: make src and tests in a new folder, and from there you can access them,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/12682491):

```
# test.py
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/utils/')

import utils
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with: `sys.path.insert(1, '.')`, but I don't understand, what is the difference between `sys.path.insert(1, '.')` and `sys.path.append('.')` ?

Comment: Not too much, it just ensures that the path is searched before other paths, including paths built into python.